# Como colocar imagem de fundo?

Tags: css, html5

Como faço para colocar uma imagem ao fundo de meu site? Não está dando certo.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Praticando #1 </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="fundo1"> Café.com </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ESTILO CASCATA

```
body{
    background-image: url ("///F:/projeto/bistro.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: A pasta "projeto" é onde o seu arquivo html esta?

Comment: Sim, a pasta está dentro do meu pendrive, com o arquivo html, css e a imagem

Comment: Já tentou colocar apenas bistro.png?

Comment: Já tentei, salvei como jpg... Fica sempre o div lá em cima sem a imagem de fundo

Comment: tente colocar no lugar de body, html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu CSS possui um erro de sintaxe:

```
               espaço errado
                     ↓
background-image: url ("///F:/projeto/bistro.png");
```

O termo `url` deve estar junto ao parênteses:

```
background-image: url("///F:/projeto/bistro.png");
```